# Windows 8 restart/shutdown gracefully

Tags: windows, shutdown

How do I restart/shutdown windows 8 gracefully?
Currently, when I restart it waits 5 sec, then kill everything, regarding nothing. I would like to do a graceful shutdown, such that when app requires a save and doesn't want to close, then I can attend to it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Why don't you save the files, then close down the machine?

Comment: How are your restarting? If you choose `logout` or `shutdown/restart` in the menus you should get a prompt that there is unsaved work with the ability to `Cancel`. When not reacting on that prompt it will cancel the shutdown itself in about 30 seconds. It could depend on the application but i just tested this with `Notepad`. Try it yourself with `Notepad`.

Comment: You are right. Please let me watch this more closely, and see why I got the impression that it does ungraceful shutdown.

Answer (score -1):

Press the Control+Alt+Delete keys simultaneously, then in the lower right-hand corner the screen you should see a power button icon (circle with a vertical line). Click the button and a new screen will appear that provides different power down options. Choose one.

Or if your computer hardware supports it, simply push the off button (might sleep instead though, that too might be configurable but it varies by manufacturer).

Comment: I am pretty sure this was only added in 8.1 and didn't exist in 8.0

Comment: What is "this"?

Comment: What you describe in the answer....

Comment: Yes, "this" shutdown procedure applies for 8.1, I confirmed on my Windows 8.1 installation.

Comment: Yes; which is my point the question was about Windows 8.0

Comment: Understood. The question just says "8" not 8.0. I thought Zohar might have meant 8.1. Either way, this follow up conversation might help those that are trying to solve the problem. Note I also suggested trying the off button.

Comment: Based on the date of the question it was `Windows 8.0` not `Windows 8.1`